# Why my indexing works with arrays but not with tuples in Rust

Tags: arrays, rust, indexing, tuples

I am totally new to rust and don't have much programming experience either. I want to write a simple game rock, scissors, paper, lizard, Spock and want randomly choose one of them from a tuple which doesn't work. But same code only with using arrays works just fine. Why is that and what should I change so that it worked with tuples too? Thank you very much.

**Variant with arrays, which works, takes one variant from an array and prints it out**:

```
    use rand::Rng;
    fn main() {
        let variants = ["rock", "scissors", "paper", "lizard", "Spock"];
        let ind: usize = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..=4);
        let choice: &str = variants[ind];   
        println!("{}",choice); 
    }
```

**Variant with tuple, which doesn't work**, it says that there is no field 'ind'

```
    use rand::Rng;
    fn main() {
        let variants = ("rock", "scissors", "paper", "lizard", "Spock");
        let ind: usize = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..=4);
        let choice: &str = variants.ind;   
        println!("{}",choice); 
    }
```

I expected that variants.ind with a tuple would work same way as variants[ind] with an array

Comment: Use an array instead. A tuple is basically a struct and you can't dynamically access fields of a struct.

Comment: If they did the same thing, then why would you need both? Just use the one that works.